# Not able to upload more than 5 images in PHP

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I'm trying to upload some images in my PHP application but I'm unable to do so. After some images, the post doesn't send data. It depends on the file size how many I can send like sometimes it works for 5 images sometimes for 3 images itself it throws this error.

```
<form action="store.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Top Image:</label><br>
    <input type="file" name="topimg" class="form-control-file" style="padding-bottom:15px;">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Sub Images:</label><br>
    <input type="file" name="img[]" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile2" multiple required>
  </div>

  <center>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="button">Save</button>
  </center>

</form>
```

This is the form I'm using and it sends data to store.php

```
$uploaddir = '../../../img/gallery/';
$dirname = "/img/gallery/";

$newname = time() . basename($_FILES['topimg']['name']);

$fileup = $dirname . $newname;
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $newname;

$img = '';
foreach ($_FILES['img']['name'] as $nam) {
  $img = $img.",".$dirname.time().$nam;
}
$img = substr($img,1);
```

The above part is for setting the name and then the code to insert into my DataBase follows this (I think it's unnecessary so I left it out)

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['topimg']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
$count=0;
foreach ($_FILES['img']['name'] as $filename)
{
  $tmp=$_FILES['img']['tmp_name'][$count];
  $count=$count + 1;
  move_uploaded_file($tmp,$uploaddir.time().$filename);
  $tmp='';
}
```

Then this code to upload the files.

So when I try to upload the files it says "Undefined index: topimg" and "Undefined index: img" with errors that relate to these being invalid. I'm I doing the PHP part wrong or is it some setting in the server. I'm using MAMP pro if this info is needed

Comment: You may be hitting an upload limit, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` directives in php.ini. See the php website https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize for more information on these directives.

To change the php.ini file for mamp pro, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37824946/how-do-you-change-php-ini-values-in-mamp-pro) question.